# converting a function object to string | "function(){...}"

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
func=function() {foo=true}
alert(JSON.stringify(func));
```

alerts "undefined"

```
obj={foo: true}
alert (JSON.stringify(obj));
```

alerts: "{foo: true}"

Why is this? As far as I understand `JSON.stringify()` converts an object to a json string, but I notice this doenst work for a "function object".

Btw searching for "function object" is hell in search engine land, because the only results I get out of google are about how objects are functions and functions are objects, but little about an actual function object.

*"The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object.*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

"Ok google: so every javascript function is an object, and every object is an function..." its the same, but it acts differenlty? I dont get it. So I am turning to stackoverflow. Can anyone enlighten me and explain why  `JSON.stringify(function() {foo=true})` does not work?

(ps. my goal is to turn `function() {foo=true}` into `"function() {foo=true}"` I am not looking for a workaround. I want to know why it doenst work to convert the function object to (json) string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Function.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)

```
var a = function() { return 1; };

console.log( a.toString() ); // "function() { return 1; }"
```

Im not sure about the support though.

Comment: It's been around since at least [ed 1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) so should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that example. I wasnt aware `toString()` could work :)

Comment: @058WistWol Note that you cannot use .toString() on native functions like alert, console.log, etc: `alert.toString()` -> `function alert() { [native code] }"`

Answer (score 1):

Reason: JSON --> JavaScript Object Notation.
JSON is a mechanism to persist (serialize) the state of a JavaScript object in a String so that it can be reused later / sent to server / process in other way.

function is not an object --> so its state cannot be serialized.

The return value of a function can however be serialized in case the return is a non-function value.

Comment: "*function is not an object*". [Yes it is](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24), however there is no serialisation for functions in the [JSON grammar](http://www.json.org).

Comment: @RobG think in terms of any programming language, a function is associated with the behavior it does and not the characteristics it holds. So calling function an object is wrong.

Comment: *"The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function   (they write "function" in sub, but still its really confusing.. is there a special function object and are functions==objects or are functions===objects or perhaps still function!==object) it doenst really mather. But still huh

Comment: A Function is an Object is JavaScript, so this answer is not as clear as it could be. To see this in action try: `var x = function() { return 42; };`, `x instanceof Function // true`, `x instanceof Object // true`. The correct answer has been mentioned by @RobG, that is the JSON specification does not describe how to serialise Functions.

Comment: _"think in terms of any programming language"_ - You can't just assume all programming languages will work the same way. Some programming languages don't have functions. Some don't have objects. In JS a function is definitely an object.